# Filebeat & test inputs

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I'm working on a Filebeat solution and I'm having a problem setting up my configuration. Let me explain my setup:

- I have a app that produces a csv file that contains data that I want to input in to ElasticSearch using Filebeats.
- I'm using Filebeat 5.6.4 running on a windows machine.
- Provided below is my filebeat.ymal configuration:

  ```
  filebeat.inputs:
  - type: log

      enabled: true

    paths:
      - C:\App\fitbit-daily-activites-heart-rate-*.log
  ```

  output.elasticsearch:

  ```
  hosts: ["http://esldemo.com:9200"]

  index: "fitbit-daily-activites-heartrate-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
  ```

  setup.template:

  ```
  name: "fitbit-daily-activites-heartrate"

  pattern: "fitbit-daily-activites-heartrate-*"

  fields: "fitbit-heartrate-fields.yml"

  overwrite: false

  settings:

    index.number_of_shards: 1

    index.number_of_replicas: 0
  ```

And my data looks like this:
0,2018-12-13 00:00:02.000,66.0,$
1,2018-12-13 00:00:07.000,66.0,$
2,2018-12-13 00:00:12.000,67.0,$
3,2018-12-13 00:00:17.000,67.0,$
4,2018-12-13 00:00:27.000,67.0,$
5,2018-12-13 00:00:37.000,66.0,$ 
6,2018-12-13 00:00:52.000,66.0,$

I'm trying to figure out why my configuration is not picking up my data and outputting it to ElasticSearch. Please help.

Comment: What do filebeat logs show ? Do they show any config or syntax error ? Documentation says you need use filebeat prospectors for configuring file input type. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/5.6/configuration-filebeat-options.html

Answer (score 0):

There are some differences in the way you configure Filebeat in versions 5.6.X and in the 6.X branch.

For 5.6.X you need to configure your input like this:

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- input_type: log
  paths:
    - 'C:/App/fitbit-daily-activites-heart-rate-*.log'
```

You also need to put your path between single quotes and use forward slashes.

[Filebeat 5.6.X configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/5.6/configuration-filebeat-options.html)